# Glade / other RAD apps vs python / XML

Tags: python, xml, gtk, gtk3

I am learning to create GUI apps using python, but I can't stand using an application that simply makes development easier than simply creating the app and layout in a lower level form. Similar to preferring HTML to WYSIWYG editors.

Anyway, is there an advantage to coding the UI myself in Python or even XML than using a RAD app like Glade? Perhaps if anyone knows of any other pygobject tutorials other than the one here - https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html - which is quite complex in my viewpoint, that would be appreciated

Comment: Aren't the tradeoffs obvious? Or are you asking if you _can_ do those things? (the answer is yes). You should probably ask your tutorial question separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coding the UI by hand is to learn, or when you have a UI that modifies itself dynamically. But for productivity, you should use Glade.